# Undefined method `embroderies' for nil:NilClass for submit create form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I set up submit form to add new data, but I got this error `undefined method`embroderies' for nil:NilClass.`
I was following the rails guide for that but I have no idea how can I correct my code.

Here is my controller.

```
class EmbroderiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
    @embroderies = Embrodery.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @embrodery = Embrodery.new
  end

  def create
    @region = Region.find(params[:region_id])
    @embrodery = @region.embroderies.create(comment_params)

    if @embrodery.save
      redirect_to @embrodery
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
  def embrodery_params
    params.require(:embrodery).permit(:name, :image)
  end
end
```

The view

```
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-xs-12 add-wrap-div">
      <p>Add new model</p>
      <%= form_for ([@region, @region.embroderies.build]) do |f| %>
        <p>
          <%= f.label :name %><br>
          <%= f.text_field :name %>
        </p>

        <p>
          <%= f.label :image %><br>
          <%= f.file_field :image %>
        </p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>
          <%= f.submit %>
        </p>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the routes

```
               Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                        Controller#Action
                 root GET    /                                                  home#index
           home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)                              home#index
           home_about GET    /home/about(.:format)                              home#about
   region_embroderies GET    /regions/:region_id/embroderies(.:format)          embroderies#index
                      POST   /regions/:region_id/embroderies(.:format)          embroderies#create
 new_region_embrodery GET    /regions/:region_id/embroderies/new(.:format)      embroderies#new
edit_region_embrodery GET    /regions/:region_id/embroderies/:id/edit(.:format) embroderies#edit
     region_embrodery GET    /regions/:region_id/embroderies/:id(.:format)      embroderies#show
                      PATCH  /regions/:region_id/embroderies/:id(.:format)      embroderies#update
                      PUT    /regions/:region_id/embroderies/:id(.:format)      embroderies#update
                      DELETE /regions/:region_id/embroderies/:id(.:format)      embroderies#destroy
              regions GET    /regions(.:format)                                 regions#index
                      POST   /regions(.:format)                                 regions#create
           new_region GET    /regions/new(.:format)                             regions#new
          edit_region GET    /regions/:id/edit(.:format)                        regions#edit
               region GET    /regions/:id(.:format)                             regions#show
                      PATCH  /regions/:id(.:format)                             regions#update
                      PUT    /regions/:id(.:format)                             regions#update
                      DELETE /regions/:id(.:format)                             regions#destroy
```

schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161115165517) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "embroderies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "image"
    t.integer  "region_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "embroderies", ["region_id"], name: "index_embroderies_on_region_id", using: :btree

  create_table "regions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "image"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "embroderies", "regions"
end
```

Comment: please also add your db schema

Comment: @Jagdeep Singh already answered correctly

Comment: @Glory Given the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `new` action, you need to find `Region` too.

```
def new
  @region = Region.find(params[:region_id])
end
```

Comment: I did it as you said but i got the error Couldn't find Region with 'id'=region_id

Comment: what is the url you are using to visit `new` page?

Comment: @Glory you need to use new_region_embrodery_path(@region) to visit this page

Comment: new_region_embrodery_path(@region)  This i should put is in my form_for
  <%= form_for new_region_embrodery_path(@region)  do |f| %> right?

Comment: No. How are you visiting the page that contains this form? By clicking some link or by pasting a url in the browser?

Comment: My mistake. I was confused. I got the idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  def new
    @region = Region.find(params[:region_id])
  end
```

**You have to intialize region here with region id**

no need to do Embrodery.new beacuse your are already building the object in form that is @region.embroderies.build

Comment: @Glory you need to use new_region_embrodery_path(@region) to visit this page

Comment: I did it it works, but i still got the same error undefined method 'embroderies'  in create action.

Comment: You fixed a bit, now in create method just put byebug and check params and let me know what are those

Comment: I posted under what you asked me, I've never done this before, so I hope I did it correctly.

Comment: aaah you missed one thing @region = Region.find(params[:region_id])  put this as first line after def create

Comment: Unfortunately, the same undefined method `embroderies'. There is something wrong in this line.

  def create
   @embrodery = @region.embroderies.create(embrodery_params)
  end

Comment: `@region = Region.find(params[:region_id])`
`@embrodery = @region.embroderies.create(comment_params)`

Added it in create

Comment: @Glory above two lines should be the first two lines of create method

Comment: you are correct, it works like this! :) I have another error now that is related with redirect_to @embrodery (undefined method `embrodery_url') but I guess it is easier to be fixed.

Comment: @Glory Great best of luck

Answer (score 0):

This is after byebug:

```
Started POST "/regions/4/embroderies" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-25 11:53:21 +0100
Processing by EmbroderiesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"v+Jt8r4ICItLjnVtNV65i49T/nxddXTt9D2An6n74wHl1WOjbPafapvEQFoRyTVALKbD8xg/z1SDJVdcMU2NqQ==", "embrodery"=>{"name"=>"gggg", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f322109b6b8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20161125-13725-1sul86f.png>, @original_filename="Screenshot from 2016-06-17 12-30-42.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"embrodery[image]\"; filename=\"Screenshot from 2016-06-17 12-30-42.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Create Embrodery", "region_id"=>"4"}

[11, 20] in /home/glory/Projects/vezba-app/app/controllers/embroderies_controller.rb
   11:     @embrodery = Embrodery.new
   12:   end
   13: 
   14:   def create
   15:     byebug
=> 16:     @embrodery = @region.embroderies.create(comment_params)
   17: 
   18:     if @embrodery.save
   19:       redirect_to @embrodery
   20:     else
(byebug) params
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"v+Jt8r4ICItLjnVtNV65i49T/nxddXTt9D2An6n74wHl1WOjbPafapvEQFoRyTVALKbD8xg/z1SDJVdcMU2NqQ==", "embrodery"=>{"name"=>"gggg", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f322109b6b8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20161125-13725-1sul86f.png>, @original_filename="Screenshot from 2016-06-17 12-30-42.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"embrodery[image]\"; filename=\"Screenshot from 2016-06-17 12-30-42.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Create Embrodery", "controller"=>"embroderies", "action"=>"create", "region_id"=>"4"}
```